# How to fix unesued import statement in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When i write import such as `import android.content.Intent;` every time it is deleted automaticly. At the below of the ide unused import statement is existing. I have searched but solutions didn't work for me. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Why would you need to manually write import statements when the IDE can do it for you? Also, what do you mean by "At the below of the ide unused import statement is existing"?

Comment: Thanks for you attention. I fixed it. Everything is ok now.